# How to prevent DataGrip from converting gregorian characters to question marks?

Tags: datagrip

I added a new row in a table. The table contains a column named `NAME_IN_GEORGIAN`, where we insert product names translated to our native language (georgian characters: `"აბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰ"`).

I've been using `pl/sql` and did not have a problem at all, but when I tried to insert a new word in `datagrip`, after commit it had been saved as question marks.

Is there anything i can do to insert georgian characters ?

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: I checked the latest DataGrip version with Oracle and PostgreSQL and insert with Georgian chars works as intended